# How to find nearest places for example(like hospital)

Tags: android, location

I am developing an app about nearest places in android . But i do not know how to calculate distance and how to sort as ascending in listview. What should i use ?

Comment: No, I just created a sqlite db  for info of places(name,lat,long...). ı can get my info of loc. But i do not know how to calculate distance of each place according to my current loc. and How to list in customlistview as ascending .

Comment: you can check out the Google Places API or the Yelp API to see if it does the required job for you

Comment: ok i will ckeck. Have you developed app about nearest places in android ?

Comment: I developed an app that queries nearby restaurants for you using the yelp api. You can do the same for hospitals. I checked the yelp developer page and they have the "hospitals" tag that you can use as a parameter. Also, see if Google Places works out better

Comment: Ok thank you can you share your source code of app with me?  just for investigating.

Answer (score 1):

I did an example like this using Foursquare service with Volley

The most important part of the project is this:

```
      private void getPlaces(){
        String apiCall = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id="+CLIENT_ID+"&client_secret="+CLIENT_SECRET+"&v=20130815%20&ll="+latitude+","+longtitude;
        JsonObjectRequest Request = new JsonObjectRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET,
                apiCall,
                (String) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("Respuesta", response.toString());


                        //Parseamos la frase
                        venuesList = (ArrayList<FoursquareVenue>) parseFoursquare(response);

                        List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<String>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < venuesList.size(); i++) {
                            listTitle.add(i, venuesList.get(i).getName() + ", " + venuesList.get(i).getCategory() + "" + venuesList.get(i).getCity());
                        }

                        // set the results to the list
                        // and show them in the xml
                        myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.listText, listTitle);
                        setListAdapter(myAdapter);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d("Respuesta", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error: "+ error.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        //Añadimos la solicitud a la cola de solicitudes
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(Request);
    }
```

Here is the entire [project](https://github.com/Gumarelo/Android-5.0/tree/master/TestFoursquare)